# Cannot set canvas.top/left with binding in ItemControl UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, wpf-controls

I want to make simple game like a snake in UWP 10 , and i want binding to rectangles in my view model observation list. I try do this , but it's not work correctly. In my XAML code i got three problem in:
Binding X
Binding Y
Binding RectItems

(Cannot resolve symbol ... due to unknow DataContext. I added my view model to context in constructor of page with xaml code so i don't know what is a problem ? Binding to Height and Width work good and i getting rectangle but all in the same position.

This is my XAML code:

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RectItems}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas  Background="Aqua"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle >
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
                </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" Fill="Black"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
```

View Model:

```
public class GameViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<RectItem> RectItems { get; set; }

    public GameViewModel()
    {
        RectItems=new ObservableCollection<RectItem>();
        RectItem rect =new RectItem() {X=50,Y=60,Width=30,Height=20}; // all properties are public double type
        RectItems.Add(rect);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Without a good [mcve] it will be difficult to know for sure what problem exists in your code. You should also provide precise detail on any errors that occur (exceptions or debug output). That said, you might try putting the binding in your `ItemTemplate` instead. I have a vague recollection that Winrt (and so probably UWP) does not support `{Binding}` syntax in style setters.

Comment: @dawcza94 did you find a solution to this? or a workaround?

Comment: @ChiragShah https://github.com/dawcza3/SnakeUWP check my project

Answer (score 1):

The ItemsControl wraps each items in ContentPresenter.
Canvas.Top/Left properties only work on direct child elements of the Canvas.
So you can use TranslateTransform.
`<Rectangle ...>`
`<Rectangle.RenderTransform>`
`<TranslateTransform X="{Binding left}" Y="{Binding top}"/>`
`</Rectangle.RenderTransform>`
`</Rectangle>`